# wordpress wpdb->update with post/request method NOT WORKING

Tags: php, database, wordpress, post, request

I have to update records in database, but it's not working. Any ideas why? 
`$wpdb->update($table_name, array( 'value' => $request['promopunk_name']),"WHERE  = 'name'");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your query like.

```
$wpdb->update($table_name, array( 'value' => $request['promopunk_name']),array("name" => 'value'));
```

i hop this is used-full for you.